# Spring Boot with Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

A design question about Spring Boot (SB) & Angular
I am quite new with SB and Angular. Is it better to have them as a seperate project, SB with Tomcat and Angular with Jetty, or embedding Angular in a SB-prjoct using same Tomcat?

I mean, should I have different repo and different releases totally independent from each other?

What do you think? Is there a best practice here?
Thank you for any thoughts/advice.

Comment: Code that changes together, should stay together.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring boot application should be used as back end and expose rest api's to consumers. Angular application as front end should consume those api's.

Comment: Do you mean that I should I have kinde of two different projects with two different releases, one Spring Boot and one Angular. Deploying to same server?

Comment: Welcome dear, Yes you need to have two different projects one for spring boot which exposes rest api's and using these api's you can send get, post, put etc requests. The Angular project should consume those api's to manipulate data using http or https requests.